# Ralink wifi dongle currently not working (but used to)

Tags: wireless, ralink

Cant get my wifi dongle to work. Plenty of topics (including those on askubuntu.com)  about those dongles, but I just cant get mine to work. I did it once, but my room mate was using this laptop while I was away. I do not know what he did in the meantime and now he's away an I cant ask.

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter

dmesg

[  +0,007837] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601

[  +0,000006] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[  +0,000003] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN

[  +0,000004] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: MediaTek

[  +0,000003] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 1.0

royal@asus:~$ lsmod | grep mt7

mt7601Usta            602112  0

royal@asus:~$ dmesg | grep mt7

[   19.267438] mt7601Usta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

did this:
http://pastebin.com/raw/0JpEwUu7
didn't help.

wat do?

Comment: Show me `dkms status`. Copy/paste that output into your original question, not the comments, please. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info.

Answer (score 1):

Disable `secure boot` in your BIOS. This will allow the driver that you installed load properly.

**Optional...**

If your driver works, you can install the `dkms` version of this driver, so you don't have to recompile it with every kernel update, add this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/mt7601
sudo apt-get update
```

Then remove the driver that you installed:

```
cd mt7601usta/src 
sudo make uninstall
```

And install the ppa driver.

Reference: https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/mt7601

Comment: I don't know why but these modules have been broken for a while.  I think it may have started with the Ubuntu 4.4 kernel but can't be sure